# redbeanphp : How to use mysql ON UPDATE timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, last-modified, redbean

I need mysql to automatically update a field on every update. I created the field as:

```
   `lastModified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

But the problem is as I update a record using R::store, the lastModified does not get updated automatically but is set to the last set value. Note that my code is not setting the field. Basically doing a findOne and store to set any other field should update the timestamp but looks like redbeans is reading the whole row (so lastUpdated is filled in as old time) and assuming when I store, it thinks I am setting it to old time value.

Comment: Can you post some simple code that demonstrates the error. I use redbeanPHP so It would be easy  to check.

Answer (score 0):

`lastModified` property is pure MYSQL. It does not depend on the implementation.

RedbeanPHP also updates mysql database, have you disabled this?

```
R::freeze( TRUE );
```

Once you put it on freeze, you can modify the database and tables yourself, and redbean will not update it. This should also take care of the `lastModified` property.

Comment: But it will still read the old value and write it back. Right ? That would make mysql think I am trying to set the new value and use it, instead of using the current timestamp. I have a workaround now where in redbeans, I exclude updates of certain fields

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$bean->lastModified = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
R::store($bean);
```

Comment: I recommend elaborating on this answer more. It seems like this doesn't answer the OPs question of "why doesn't the timestamp update automatically".

Comment: sorry for my short answer,
it seems redbean only updates what fields has changed in the bean, so if it was set `lastModified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  in database, either set the bean property to null or current time to make data change